# Test if an add-on sdk firefox extension is installed

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

my question is in the subject.
I need to be able to test if my add-on sdk based extension is installed in order to open it programmatically.
How would I do that ?
Basically, I have a JS script checking for the web browser of the user and if my extension is installed, I'd like to redirect to a specific url, which will launch the opening of the extension.
I read that with XUL extension, adding a contentaccessible=yes to any image and testing it onload gives us the answer, but it seems we can't do that with add-on sdk based...

Any idea ?

Thanks anyway for reading me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the docs for the AddonManager:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager

Here is a code snippet that you coulde use to get going:

```
const { Cu } = require("chrome");

let AddonManager = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm").AddonManager;

AddonManager.getAddonsByTypes(["extension"], function(addons) {
    var addonData = [];

    for (let i in addons) {
        let cur = addons[i];
        addonData.push({
            id: cur.id.toString(),
            name: cur.name,
        });
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(addonData, null, '   '));
});
```

<del>I've hosted this code on the Add-on Builder as well:</del>

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/44810/latest/

**Edit: Builder is EOL and will go offline in a month.**